# want $\dot\rho(t)$ in the simplified matrix form. Can someone please help me?

Tags: calculus

$\dot\rho(t)=-i[H_0,\rho]-\frac{\gamma}{2}(A^2\rho(t) + \rho(t)A^2 - 2A\rho(t)A)$ where,
$A =|1><1|+\eta|2><2|$ where $\eta$=const
and

$H_0 =\delta_p|2><2| + (\frac{\Omega_s}{2}|1><2| + \frac{\Omega_p}{2}|0><2| + H.C)$
I need to solve the Lindblad equation in the eigenbasis of $H_0$.
The eigenbasis are
$|D>=\frac{\Omega_s}{\Omega_0}|0>-\frac{\Omega_p}{\Omega_0}|1>$;
$|->=(\frac{\Omega_p}{\Omega_0}|0>+\frac{\Omega_s}{\Omega_0}|1>)Cos\phi - Sin\phi|2>$;
$|+>=(\frac{\Omega_p}{\Omega_0}|0>+\frac{\Omega_s}{\Omega_0}|1>)Sin\phi + Cos\phi|2>$;
and $tan\phi = \frac{\Omega_0}{\delta_p +\sqrt{\delta_p^2+\Omega_0^2}}$

I want $\dot\rho(t)$ in the simplified matrix form. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use `\langle,\rangle` to render $\langle,\rangle$ more appropriately